# Error "Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract." for standard token

Tags: tokens, compilation, solc

When I try to create a new instance of the [standard token](https://ethereum.org/token), compiler throws an error:
`Error: Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract.`

I suppose it is due to abstract receiveApproval function specified in standard token:
`contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }`

If I'm right, then how to deploy standard token contract from within another contract?

Update:
Code, compiler and error in the browser-solidity:
https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js&gist=d033d42efe4975df632dff74e889dd05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with how constructor's inheritance and constructor parameters work.

In your case, **MyAdvancedToken** inherits from **token**, and token takes parameters so you need to pass something to it during creation phase.

To fix your code, replace MyAdvancedToken constructor with

```
/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol,
        address centralMinter
    ) token (initialSupply, tokenName, decimalUnits, tokenSymbol) {
        if(centralMinter != 0 ) owner = msg.sender;         // Sets the minter
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        totalSupply = initialSupply;
    }
```

and it will compile as expected.

I created a [simpler example](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js&gist=d36c09d53ee5a9d1802dafe04d0bf0e0) to better show this behavior.

Comment: Cool.
Does this mean that code part in MyAdvancedToken() function that already present in token() function isn't needed after that change?
And can I do similar thing for any other function in MyAdvacedToken that is defined in token?

Comment: Right. When a contract inherits another one, it can use all methods of the parent. You can also override parent methods - that is what you actually did - if you want to change the method behavior. If you want to call the actual overridden method and your custom code, you can do something like this: function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) { super.transfer(address _to, uint256 _value); //add more code here } in your MyAdvancedToken contract.

Comment: At http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-in-depth.html and at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features you can find very extensive documentation about how Solidity works.

Answer (score 1):

#### Successful Deployment With Ethereum Wallet 0.6.2 And 0.7.3 On Linux

I have just tested out the code under the "The Code" section in the page [Create your own crypto-currency with Ethereum](https://ethereum.org/token#deploying) using Ethereum Wallet (Mist) 0.6.2 on Linux deploying on Testnet.

The contract compiled and deployed successfully. You can find the Testnet contract details at [0xe48f4d015847ca794e2f8769d70acffe92db4f176b8b5ee26c91dfe765cae95d](http://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xe48f4d015847ca794e2f8769d70acffe92db4f176b8b5ee26c91dfe765cae95d)

Note that I have previously synced the Testnet blockchain and used Mist to mine the blockchain to earn some Testnet ethers.

I retested using Ethereum Wallet 0.7.3 on Linux and successfully deployed the contract. You can find the second Testnet contract details at [0x41cefb2cf0709dac540695ac134b05ab0322acfa8443bdd632bdf3c86c4d3c34](http://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x41cefb2cf0709dac540695ac134b05ab0322acfa8443bdd632bdf3c86c4d3c34) .

---

#### Unable To Compile In `geth`

I tried compiling and deploying the contract using `geth` and could not get it to compile correctly.

I stripped out all the `/* ... */` and `//` comments and removed all the newlines to generate the following statement to be executed in `geth`:

```
> var sampleTokenSource='contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }contract MyToken {  string public standard = 'Token 0.1'; string public name; string public symbol; uint8 public decimals; uint256 public totalSupply;  mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf; mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);  function MyToken( uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, uint8 decimalUnits, string tokenSymbol ) { balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;  totalSupply = initialSupply;  name = tokenName;  symbol = tokenSymbol;  decimals = decimalUnits;  }  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) { if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;  if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;  balanceOf[_to] += _value;  Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);  }  function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) { allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender); spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData); return true; }  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) { if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;  if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;  balanceOf[_from] -= _value;  balanceOf[_to] += _value;  allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value; Transfer(_from, _to, _value); return true; }  function () { throw;  }}'
(anonymous): Line 1:188 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)
```

---

### Questions For You

- What software are you using to compile your contract? What version? What operating system?
- What are the steps you are performing?

Comment: I have updated the question with link to code, compiler and error.

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when a contract tries to define abstract and implemented functions together, i.e,

```
contract foobar {
    function foo();  // will throw error.
    function bar() {}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, mixing abstract and concrete methods is an issue, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer in this post: [Truffle V3.1.9, error running migrations](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12328/truffle-v3-1-9-error-running-migrations/15418#15418)

Short version: You most likely have a function making your contract abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error because I didn't call the base constructor in the child class

```
contract Child is Parent //inherits from contract "Parent"
{
    constructor(address _token)
        public
        Parent(_token) //<-if Parent has ctor and left might lead to this error
    {
    }
}
```