# Truffle V3.1.9, error running migrations

Tags: dapp-development, contract-deployment, testnets, truffle

Hey I'm updating my truffle project from V2 to V3, and I am getting this error after migrating:

```
sudo truffle migrate --network development
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Migrations error: contract binary not set. Can't deploy new instance.
    at Function.new (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:324:15)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-migrate/node_modules/truffle-deployer/src/actions/deploy.js:25:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Here is my truffle.js file:

```
module.exports = {
networks: {
development: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8545,
  network_id: "*"
},
staging: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8546,
  network_id: 1337
},
ropsten: {
  host: "158.253.8.12",
  port: 8545,
  network_id: 3
}
```

}
}

Deploy contracts file:

```
var Project = artifacts.require("./Project.sol");
var FundingHub = artifacts.require("./FundingHub.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Project);
  deployer.deploy(FundingHub);
};
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with nuances in 3.x yet, but in 2.x that sort of thing looks familiar. Commonly happens when the deployer account is locked. "Network State Unknown" is a little perplexing until you get used to it.

Comment: Hmm soo that would be the testrpc account?

Comment: If testrpc, try $ testrpc -u 0 -u 1 .... unlocks accounts 0 and 1 which are not unlocked by default if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ok I reverted back to Truffle 2 for now, but will try it once I'm finished current project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one function that is an abstract function in your contract.

`function addr(string _name) constant returns (address o_owner)`

The whole contract is compiled as an abstract contract, so you will get this error message.
It might be like me, that you never ment to write an abstract contract, but a but fast copy pasting of some code, and simsallabim, you have some abstract functions without thinking about it.
So either add functions bodies to them or remove them.

Then your contract will compile.